# Should a common database/dao methods be static?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, static

I have a method that is used 3-4 times within my code from various locations. Usually one would introduce a static utility method for this, which I also did.

But I wonder if this is a good practice, if this static method executes some database/dao logic? Take the following as a pseudocode example:

```
class DaoUtiliy {

    public static void updateToDB(List a, List b) {
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        dao.open(); //begin transaction     

        //create some variables using the list a, that are used to fetch the db entry:
        String time, String date; //some more
        Entity entity = dao.find(time, date);

        //update anything in that entity;
        entity.setProperty(b.get(0));

        dao.close(); //commit transaction
    }   
}
```

Would you put this also in a static method? Or rather create a `new DaoService().updateToDB(a, b);` anc call this method from where it is needed?

Comment: So you're allocating Hibernate Sessions in the constructor of Dao?  Or they are on a ThreadLocal somewhere that it grabs?

Comment: I'm fetching `EntityManager` in the dao itself on instantiation: `EntityManager em = EMUtil.get();`

Comment: and EMUtil gets it from???  Where I am going is that while this is fine it leaves you no ability to alter your session lifecycle or expand the scope of your units of work as your requirements grow and the project evolves.  You are coupled to all units of work being defined as stand alone static method, which gets ugly.

Comment: Gets it from `EntityManagerFactory` etc. I know my example might not be the flexible one for db access, but my question was more about the architecture of methods doing db stuff, not the EM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer non static methods in DAO for the following reasons

1. Making them non static makes it easier to inject values using frameworks like Spring
2. Writing unit test cases is not easier for static methods since they cannot be overridden
3. Also if you want to extend the functionality of your DAO overriding of static methods is not possible.